# send multipart entity data from iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, multipartentity

I use following code to send Multipart Entity data to server and server give me 403 response everytime.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.britecase.com/administrator/components/com_ivmstore/ivmwebservices/vmphotos.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"files[]\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type:application/octet-stream \r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90)]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];


    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

I got following response each and everytime.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /administrator/components/com_ivmstore/ivmwebservices/vmphotos.php
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.britecase.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

There is a successful response from our android application. Here I come to know that they are using following code for multipart Entity for `browser compatible`.

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Looks like an authentication issue to me. I am not sure about the android part. Any idea for what purpose that is used and if they remove that what is happening?

Comment: @ACB they provide property which is BROWSER_COMPATIBLE. in iphone which property we have to provide ?

Comment: I haven't heard of any such property in iOS. Is it possible to check with them, for what purpose they are using this property. And in case they dont pass that, what is the response they are getting? Is it same as yours?

Comment: Okay. got this from google, "If BROWSER_COMPATIBLE is specified instead, the data sent by http commons does not contain any Content-Transfer-Encoding header". I dont think iOS will be sending any such header in request. In android, by default it sends this and if they want to avoid that they uses this it seems. So the issue could be with your boundary or so.